# Preserve old values on error in setting API

Tags: settings-api, sanitization, errors

I am trying to preserve old value of form when it fails the validation defined in sanitize callback of register_setting.
But it does not do so, instead it save the default values

```
register_setting('setting-wpse3401', 'wpse3401_options', array( 'sanitize_callback' => [$this, 'wpse3401_sanitize_value']));

public function wpse3401_sanitize_value( $val )
{
    $newval = array();
    $type = 'updated';
    $msg = 'Settings is saved!';    

    $newval['form_field_0'] = sanitize_text_field($val['form_field_0']);
    if( $val['form_field_1'] < 1 ) {
        $type = 'error';
        $msg = 'Please enter number greater than 0'
    } else {
        $newval['form_field_1'] = $val['form_field_1'];
    }

    add_settings_error('wpse3401_messages', 'wpse3401_message', __($msg, 'text-domain'), $type);

    if($type == 'updated'){
        return $newval;
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still no answer ? I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately WordPress does not provide the old value as an additional argument to your `sanitize_callback` callable. This is supported in general by the [option validator hook that WordPress calls when saving the updated setting](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4848a09b3593b639bd9c3ccfcd6038e90adf5866/wp-includes/formatting.php#L4651)...

```
return apply_filters( "sanitize_option_{$option}", $value, $option, $original_value );
```

...but in practice [it is not actually registered with any additional arguments when the filter is added during `register_setting`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4848a09b3593b639bd9c3ccfcd6038e90adf5866/wp-includes/option.php#L2114):

```
if ( ! empty( $args['sanitize_callback'] ) ) {
    add_filter( "sanitize_option_{$option_name}", $args['sanitize_callback'] );
}
```

Because `add_filter` doesn't specify that the callable takes any additional arguments, `apply_filter` does not provide `$option` or `$original_value` to your callback when it is called (I consider this to be a bug, and have submitted a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43629) to the developers). This means you cannot use the `$original_value` to fall back on when the provided setting is invalid. Instead, I suggest you just grab the current setting's value within your callback:

```
if ( 'updated' === $type ) {
    return $newval;
} else {
    // use previous value
    return get_option( 'wpse3401_options' );
}
```